# Find all points $(x,y)$ on the graph of $y = \frac{x}{x-4}$ with tangent lines perpendicular to the line $y = 4x - 3$

Tags: calculus

I should find the slope of the given line and the tangent to the given curve.

I'm unsure of how to proceed with this though.

I know that the slope of the tangent line is equal to $y'$ at any point on the curve.

Comment: You're right that the slope of the tangent is equal to $y'$ at any point. So did you calculate $y'$? If not, where are you stuck?

Comment: The lines perpendicular to $y=4x-3$ are lines with the slope $-1/4$. So simply solve $y'(x)=-1/4$ for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let be:
$$
f(x,y)=y-\frac{x}{x-4}=0
$$

Compute $\nabla f$:
$$
\nabla f=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)=
\left(\frac{4}{(x-4)^2},1\right)
$$

Let be:
$$
g(x,y)=y-4x+3=0
$$

The equation of the given line. Now, compute $\nabla g$:
$$
\nabla g =\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x},\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right)=
(-4,1)
$$

Compute the dot product ${\nabla f}\cdot{\nabla g}$ and make it equals zero:
$$
-\frac{16}{(x-4)^2}+1=0
$$
$$
\left|x-4\right|=4
$$

From this equation you get $x_1=0$ and $x_2=8$. Thereafter, you obtain $y_1=0$ and $y_2=2$. Finally, the points you are looking for are:
$$
(x_{1},y_{1})=(0,0)
$$
$$
(x_{2},y_{2})=(8,2)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

So, the required tangent will of the form $$x+4y=p$$ where $p$ is an arbitrary constant.

Though the problem has been tagged as 'Calculus', I am tempted to supply one generalized solution based on quadratic equation.

If $x+4y=p$ has to be a tangent of any quadratic curve $$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$$

replace the $x$ with $p-4y$ to form a quadratic equation in $y$

The two roots represent the [ordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abscissa_and_ordinate)  of the intersections(s).

For tangency, the two ordinates must coincide $\iff$ the roots must be same.